# What are disadvantages of wood floor covering in shower?

Tags: shower, hardwood-floor

I love the idea of the luxurious texture of wood flooring in a shower. Does this add significant maintenance/cleaning concerns to the shower?

[image: Wood floor cover in shower]

Comment: Wood and water don't tend to mix very well.

Comment: You would definitely not use wood as the actual base of the shower. If anything, the wood would simply sit on top of a tile or vinyl floor which is a standard shower floor. The wood used would have to be something that can stand up to a lot of moisture (eg, a tropical wood or composite). You also need it to drain appropriately, eg, lots of spacers between pieces of wood, as standing water will rot and grow mould.

Comment: The floor in that picture is almost certainly linoleum or vinyl tile

Comment: Another option would be a wood grain looking ceramic or porcelean tile.

Comment: @bemace, I thought the floor in the shot looked a lot like [Ikea's PLATTA](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/20165486/). If that example is not real wood, there are lots of examples of real wood in "glamor" shots of showers: [google image search: "wood shower"](https://www.google.com/search?q=wood+shower&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=GRMkUInEMbD0iwLlu4DwCw&biw=1280&bih=908&sei=HBMkUJW1E67nigKH9ICYCA) I'm wondering how functional it is in real applications.

Comment: It's possible, I've never seen that type of flooring before. Either way your question is fine, just wanted to mention it.

Comment: The wood in that shower looks like wood deck panels. Ipe or teak or other outdoor wood attached to plastic grids that snap together. So, you still need a proper shower pan and tiled floor, but could simply place those on top. They'll eventually get gunky and you'll want to replacement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are woods used in wet environments, mostly those that are fairly impervious to rot - teak, cedar, redwood, mahogony (less so).

**Untreated:** Sometimes cedar, redwood and teak are left natural. In almost all these cases, they are not exposed to prolonged soaking.  Even in saunas they are misted and then dried, not soaked the way a shower soaks. On Boats they get spashed, they dry.  When they are left untreated, the wood weathers, loses its color and eventually becomes somewhat rough. Cedar and redwood are fairly soft, and on a floor will wear out, probably quickly. Teak will last longer but will roughen up and wear out eventually. Also untreated wood tends to hold water and is more prone to developing mold or organic growths, such as bacteria, especially in a shower that is not exposed to sunlight.

**Treated:** These woods can be finished with a penetrating sealer or a hard marine finish, like spar varnish or the harder polyurethanes, or even an epoxy finish. Even then, these finishes need to be redone often, sometimes every year, depending on the amount of soaking and other wear.

Finished or sealed Wood can be used in bathrooms where there is just an occasional spash or where the wet is quickly mopped up. I have hard pine floors finished with several coats of poly in my bathroom that works fine. My shower is a porcelain tub.

On the whole, it would be very questionable to put wood in a shower floor.

**Disclaimer:** Recently, exotic hardwoods have come into widespread use in the US for porches and decks. Ipe, cumaru, and other South American hardwoods can handle repeated wettings without significant deterioration except fading. They often need special tools for cutting and drilling, since they are very hard. But note that, even in deck use, the soaking is probably not as complete and frequent as a shower. These woods can be treated with special oil to prolong life and improve water handling.

Comment: Adding to this great answer... Ipe handles wetness very similar to Teak, Cumaru and other Brazilian hardwoods. A penetrating oil stain designed for Brazilian hardwoods is my recommendation if you go with these. I use Ipe oil.

Comment: @LarryMaccherone Excellent addition. I will add it. Five years ago, when this was written, these were not so much on the DIY radar. I since have rebuilt a porch using untreated ipe.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry I didn't check back and see your question re: maintenance and cleaning, etc. I used ipe decking in my master bath shower, raised off the tile floor with rubber feet. I rinse the ipe off soap scum after every shower, this takes about 5-10 seconds. Every regular cleaning the wood is lifted out, tile cleaned normally. I have a hard brush to scrub off any residual soap scum on the ipe, there usually isn't any. Two adults use this shower daily, but the wood does dry out completely over the course of the day/night. It is not continuously wet.

I've had the ipe for more than two years without issue, no mold or other concerns. Ipe is heavy, however, and removing it every week or two to clean the tile may be difficult.

Comment: Hi! It looks like you’ve accidentally created a couple of accounts. If you’d like to merge them (there are some [advantages](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) to doing so), the instructions are [here](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Welcome to the site!